# Alamofire - Certificate Pinning testing - how to print out reason

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

With Alamofire 3.x, is there any way to print out the reasons that a serverTrustPolicy fails?  At the moment I am manually changing the values from true to false to test bad certs.  In this example, my definition of a bad cert == self-signed or incorrect hostname.

```
class PinningManager {

    var manager: Manager?

    init() {
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "google.com": .PinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            ),
            "httpbin.org": .DisableEvaluation
        ]

        manager = Alamofire.Manager(
            configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
    }
}
```